# The exponential map by one-parameter subgroup on linear Lie group

Tags: definition, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

Let $G$ be a linear Lie group, it is known that the exponential map on $G$ is $\exp(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}$.

If $G$ is not necessarily a linear Lie group, then the exponential map defined (in a modern way) by the one-parameter subgroup.

Why is the exponential map with the one-parameter subgroup coincide with $\exp(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}$ where $G$ is a linear Lie group? More specifically, what is the one-parameter subgroup (corresponding to $x\in T_eG$) where $G=Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $G=Gl_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: The exponential map gives the correspondence between one-parameter subgroups of a Lie group (more precise their corresponding subalgebras in the Lie Algebra associated with the Lie Group), and the action of smooth vector fields on the manifold upon which it acts. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory) for more info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-parameter subgroup corresponding to $X\in\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb R)(=T_eGL_n(\Bbb R))$ is the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi_X\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&GL_n(\Bbb R)\\&t&\mapsto&\exp(tX).\end{array}$$It's clearly a group homomorphism and $\varphi_X'(0)=X$. The same thing works with $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Is that useful being a group homomorphism here?

Comment: @C.F.G Yes, since that's part of the definition of one-parameter subgroup.